# How to get Twitter screen_name with Prisma/nextauth?

Tags: oauth, prisma

I'm using Postgres,prisma,nextauth.
try to get twitter username(screen_name)

this is my schema.prisma.

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?

  screenname      String    @unique
  screen_name      String    @unique
  username      String    @unique

  email         String?   @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}
```

> > > Argument username for data.screenname is missing.\n' +

> > > Argument username for data.username is missing.\n' +

> > > Argument username for data.screen_name is missing.\n' +